# Firebase App Indexing Test always fails

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

When using the implementation test from
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/ios/test
I always get the following error:
`ERROR:Google did not find App content associated with the URL.`

I made sure that universal links work (i.e. open the app instead of browser on iOS device) for the entered url (which is a https:// url).

What could be the reason for this behaviour?